# Why would a C# Winforms TextBox display nothing when using a large string taken from a file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a large string in the format HH-HH-HH-...-HH-HH-HH where HH is a byte written as a hex value.  The string I'm trying to put in my text box has 78574 hex bytes plus the dashes in it.  The Text field correctly holds the string (I can see it while debugging and it writes to console fine), but the string isn't being displayed in the textbox (the text box is empty).

this is how I get the data and write to the textbox

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
textbox.Text = BitConverter.ToString(fileBytes);
```

It works fine with very small files (20 bytes), but a hundred or more and it starts behaving as mentioned above.

an example of a string that works (it's just a one liner text file)

```
54-68-69-73-20-69-73-20-61-20-74-65-78-74-20-64-6F-63-75-6D-65-6E-74-20-66-6F-72-20-74-65-73-74-69-6E-67-2E
```

the above works when repeated 56 times but doesn't work if I repeat it 57 times.

Any ideas on why it won't show longer strings and how I might make it display them?

Edit: I changed the title to better represent my question.  This is not a duplicate as far as I can tell.

Comment: It keels over when the width of the displayed string exceeds 32767 pixels.  You are well beyond the "crazy unusable UI" stage by then.

Comment: My textbox size is fixed, it's not running across a few hundred screens.  I want to display it so that a user can , Ctrl A, Ctrl C, and then paste the content somewhere else.  Not so "crazy unusable" in my opinion.  Is there a way to override the limit you mentioned?

Comment: No, it is hard-baked limit.

Comment: Why is there a max char limit of 2147483646 if you can't possibly add that much?

Comment: You can, but that requires Multiline = true.  The non-crazy UI alternative, the user can actually see the text.

Comment: That almost works, thanks.  Is there a way to turn on multiline without disabling Ctrl A to select all?  I need the user to be able to copy everything from the box, but they don't need to see it all, this isn't an editor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15915059/17034

Comment: The content is there, just not displayed after copying it in.. Also note that the same restriction is true for the Height. Also note that the choice of fonts can make things worse or (fractionally) better..

Comment: If they don't need to see it all, do they need to see it at all? You could just have a button "Copy to clipboard" and that's it

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen good point.  I might find a way to make that work for larger files.  I need to have a text box so that the can manually enter in the data if it's short or they don't have a file to load.

Answer (score -1):

You can try and change property of textbox. I have used `textbox1.MaxLength = 2147483647;`

This serves my maximum number of characters that can be displayed in textbox.