Prevent windows from beeping when pressing alt+a inside a textbox on a form with a menu in visual basic 6
The problem I have is, I have a text input field, and I want to add a shortcut key of alt+1 alt+2 alt+3 and alt+a
I handle the keydown, with key preview enabled, and set the keycode to 0 to prevent other weird behaviour.
However, because I have a dropdown menu, visual basic triggers it from my alt shortcut. It looks for a menu item where the first letter (or shortcut) matches what I pressed. So if I press alt+a it looks for a menu item starting with a.
If it finds it, it will press it. If it doesn't find it, if your sound effects in control panel are set to beep on error, it will play a 'Ding' error sound.
The only workaround I've been able to find is to create a menu item, &a &1 &2 &3 etc (has to be a top level item) and set them to disabled=true. This stops the beep and my program functions perfectly.
What I'd like to do is stop the beep without having all these menus in the dropdown menu.
I've tried the following:

all manner of keydown, keypress, keycode=0 keyascii=0 attempts on both the form and the input control. No luck.

visibility hidden on the items, doesn't work, beep comes back

using an API method to dynamically change the caption to "". It seems this updates the shortcut as well


Perhaps there's a way to shrink them to 0px wide? Or to use the 'Shortcut' property to specify alt+a (although alt+number isn't listed, ctrl+number is).
Or to update the caption without updating the shortcut?
Open to ideas on how to hack this thing so they're invisible, or otherwise fix this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15915059/17034

Why is this tagged "Winforms" which is VB.NET, not VB6?

This code worked for me only on left ALT+keys by using virtual ALT keyup. Not beeping.
Option Explicit

Private Const VK_ALT = &H12
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Dim intScanALT As Integer
 
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Declare Function MapVirtualKey Lib "user32" Alias "MapVirtualKeyA" (ByVal wCode As Long, ByVal wMapType As Long) As Long

Private Sub Text_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
intScanALT = MapVirtualKey(VK_ALT, 0)
keybd_event VK_ALT, intScanALT, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Sub

Private Sub Text_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
KeyCode = 0
End Sub

